# Efficiency of pulling database regularly for doing statistics and ML statements for real-time analysis

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-performance

I work with a data scientist to analyze data that are currently stored in postgresql database in real-time.

We've got the idea to pull some data from the database regularly (from a timestamps) using a interval of time. It seems a good idea but I'm worry about the efficiency of doing this with a relational database.

The query is simple, it selects data from a single table without any join. But the database can be populate at the same time we extract information from it. So we're worried about the efficency of this approach.

Is there any better pattern or tool for doing that ? What about prometheus ?
I hope that I post this in the right stackexchange.

Thank you for reading

Comment: "*But the database can be populate at the same time we extract information from it. So we're worried about the efficency of this approach.*" - What specifically is your concern with this approach from an efficiency standpoint?...Locking?